# How to check if excel sheets exists in Kettle ETL?

Tags: etl, kettle

I'm looping a directory and load all excel files where sheet name is like "Data".

If no sheet is named like "Data", I'm expecting the transformation to abort or throw an error. I have tried to use "switch-case", set default step to "Abort" if the sheet name does not equal to "Data", but this does not work. The work flow would go to both "Abort" and "Data" direction.

So how I achieve this? Just like doing an if else in Kettle? In SSIS, I can manage to use the variable to determine the work direction, but it seems that I could not use variable in Kettle.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution.
USING Simple Evaluation to check for a variable value.
SET this variable value within the job:

- Get sheet name from Microsoft Excel Input
- Output this variable at the end of the job using [Set Variable], give it a dummy variable value
- Check this variable at the parent transformation, if it equals to specific value, then continue the work flow, else abort

Answer (score 0):

You can't set and read Variables in the same transformation.
In your case, get count of "Data sheets" by "group by" step and next simply call Abort in case of count=0.